# How to handle mangled HTTP POST on cellular networks

Tags: http, cellular-network

I have a website that is primarily used by mobile clients. There are numerous form posts and ajax POST requests coming in from the site and 95% of the time they work fine, but the rest of the requests fail with an error because an expected POST body param is missing. I can see people trying repeatedly to submit some data over and over in the logs, with no luck because (and I'm using Spring MVC here) the framework is throwing a MissingServletRequestParameterException.

It's always for the same parameter names too. I have not been able to recreate this problem on any device on any network (here in Canada) but it's clearly happening on other networks around the world.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? I'm feeling like I might be the only one, because no matter what I search for on google or SO I can't find anything even remotely similar.

There is nothing complex about the post data - there might be at most 3 values; no weird naming conventions.

E.g.

```
POST /handleruri HTTP/1.1
Host: somehost.com

id=H4543&date=20-08-2012
```

UPDATE:

Just having looked at some more log entries, I don't think that ANY post data is coming through for those failed requests, as I'm not only not seeing the param name as per the exception thrown by Spring MVC, but I'm not seeing any of the other param names (I'm logging the entire request on error, but unfortunately by the time a raw HTTP request makes it to a servlet {DispatchServlet in this case} it's been processed and the original raw request body InputStream has been consumed).

I will be writing a ServletFilter soon to try and get at the raw request body and also log this.

If this is a carrier specific problem, I don't know what I'm going to do to resolve it - doesn't seem that there is much I CAN do.

Appreciate help from anyone who has gone through this before.

Thanks

Comment: As I am unable to reproduce this myself and can't perform network packet traces on the server, no. At least, not with my current know-how. Is it possible to do this on a production server in a safe way?

Comment: Probably not. Can you get a test server running the same environment?

Comment: We only experience these problems when users are coming in over a cellular network and using their carrier's proxies. I implemented that ServletFilter to allow us to log failing requests and as part of it's implementation I used an HttpServletRequestWrapper sub-class which has to provide functionality such as getParameters() - I implemented this functionality and performed some simple cleanup on the POST data such as trimming the POST var keys and suddenly all the errors went away (well almost all). The act of parsing the POST data ourselves has helped.

Comment: It's probably the carrier's proxy's fault and chances are there isn't anything you can do about it.